# How to fix solana-test-validator Illegal instruction (core dumped) error even after building from source?

Tags: solana-cli, anchor-test, solana-test-validator

When running `anchor test` on a fresh project without any change, I got following error:

> Unable to get recent blockhash. Test validator does not look started.
> Check {} for errors. Consider increasing [test.startup_wait] in
> Anchor.toml.

I first tried increasing `startup_wait` as suggested, but that didn't worked, then tried running `solana-test-validator --log` and saw error was:

> Aborted (core dumped)

So I also tried building it from source as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812395/aborted-core-dumped-in-solana-test-validator), but got another error when running `solana-test-validator --log` again:

> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Answer (score 5):

If you already tried all this and still getting `Illegal instruction` error, you probably need to change some compilation variables.

In my case, the problem was the old CPU (older than 2013) and fixed by setting:

```
export RUST_REED_SOLOMON_ERASURE_ARCH=native
```

and then compiling all:

```
./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
```

as mentioned in this [Issue's comment](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/28366#issuecomment-1302667020)

Answer (score 0):

My CPU had no AVX2 and I had to additionally disable it like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana
cd solana
git checkout v1.16.18

cargo clean

export RUST_REED_SOLOMON_ERASURE_ARCH=native
export RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=-avx2"

./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .

export PATH="$PWD"/bin:"$PATH"
```

Try running `cargo clean` before the new build since incremental compilation might reuse binaries built with previous compiler options. The build populates the `./bin` and `./target` folders.

`solana-install init` is of no need here if you are fine with running the binaries from the cloned git repository.